# How to embed a Yandex map in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, yandex-maps, yandex-api

I have a Yandex map widget and I want to embed it in an Angular component. I am using Angular(v6)

I tried to embed scripts and the root element in a tree:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.renderMapWidget();
}

renderMapWidget() {
  const ymapsScript = document.createElement('script');
  ymapsScript.src = '//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?load=package.standard&lang=ru_RU';

  const ymapsWidgetScript = document.createElement('script');
  ymapsWidgetScript.src = '//...............';

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(ymapsScript);
    document.body.appendChild(ymapsWidgetScript);
  }, 2000);
}
```

template:

```
<div id="widget-container"></div>
```

Inspecting the widget in Chrome shows that the widgets root element is displayed, but the element is empty. Also I am not seeing any errors in the console output.

Comment: What package are you using - is it [angular2-yandex-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-yandex-maps)? Also would you update your question to include the relevant HTML?

Comment: native yandex maps api. no angular package

Answer (score 2):

In order to embed Yandex map on angular component, I did following steps:

1. Added following script in main index.html(link to yandex maps api may differ by version):

   ```
   <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=YOUR_YANDEX_API_KEY&lang=en_US" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
2. The component where I wanted to embed the map:

   ```
   import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
   import {AdBoardAddDialogService} from "app/home/ad-board-add-dialog.service";

   declare const ymaps: any;

   @Component({
     selector: 'jhi-home',
     templateUrl: './yandex-maps.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['home.scss'],
   })
   export class YandexMapsComponent implements OnInit {
     map: any;
     latitude = 41.3;
     longitude = 69.3;
     @ViewChild('yamaps')
     el!: ElementRef;

     constructor(private adBoardAddDialogService: AdBoardAddDialogService) {
     }

     ngOnInit(): void {
       ymaps.ready().done(() => this.createMap());
     }

     private createMap(): void {
       this.map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
         center: [this.latitude, this.longitude],
         zoom: 14
       });

       const placeMark = new ymaps.Placemark([this.latitude, this.longitude]);
       this.map.geoObjects.add(placeMark);
     }

   }
   ```
3. And here is my yandex-maps.component.html:

   ```
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 600px" #yamaps>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

One can change size of the map given in html code.